# Django email sending, but not received

Tags: django, django-email

I know this has gotten asked a hundred times, I've gone through most of the past questions and still cannot email to send from Django. The send-email folder has a copy, meaning all of the test emails are sending, but they never reach my gmail account.

I turned access to less secure websites on my gmail account, so it should work, but does not seem to.

Here is my settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'pass'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Not sure, why it's not working.

Comment: Have you checked spam?

Comment: try commenting out `EMAIL_BACKEND`

Comment: I commented it out and it still supposedly sent. There is a copy of the email at timestamp in my sent_emails folder. However, I again did not receive.

Comment: If there is a copy of the email in your sent folder, then the problem isn't in Django. We can't tell why the emails aren't being delivered from gmail to the destination. I would consider using a different email provider e.g. sendgrid/mailgun/AWS SES with [django-anymail](https://github.com/anymail/django-anymail).

Comment: Any suggestions on a good free email provider for this task?

Comment: Recommendations are off topic for Stack Overflow. You could look at the three I named above, or the others that django-anymail supports.

Answer (score 0):

Try send an email from host id to your gmail without using django . Both the emails will reach your gmail account . I dont know why but this works