# Django email sending but not received

Tags: python, django

In my django project I am trying to send a message. There is a message in the sent ones, but I do not receive it. The letter is not in spam.

This my settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

I tried to do what is written here
[Django email sending, but not received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479080/django-email-sending-but-not-received)

This is sending code:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activate account'
            message = render_to_string('registration/acc_active_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
            email.send()

            message_email_confirm = 'Message'
            return render(request, 'registration/email_confirmation_page.html', {'message': message_email_confirm})
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
        return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: read this and then try maybe you have some issue

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/13/how-to-send-email.html

Comment: Can you add your sending code?

Comment: did you allow less secure apps? https://www.arclab.com/en/kb/email/how-to-enable-imap-pop3-smtp-gmail-account.html

Comment: @rzlvmp Yes, I did